# Static folder is not loading in my html template

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Hello I am new to django in python
I am working on a website and I am facing some errors while loading static files in my html template

here are some of my codes:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'ImperfectCoder'
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",

]
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('blog', views.blog, name='blog')
]
```

tried to load the static by

```
{% load static %}
```

And implement it by

```
<img src = "{% static'art-design-2.jpg' %}" alt = "">
```

The following error comes

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /blog
Invalid block tag on line 56: 'static'art-design-2.jpg''. Did you forget to register or load this 
tag?
```

Another hint I got that in vs code I have installed django extension and when i load the static files it automaticlly shows what to write but this time it didin't please help me with this

Comment: You missed a space.

Comment: But where did I

Comment: It should get clearer if you look at the code quoted in the error message. Remember that template tags are not HTML, they have stricter rules for spacing.

Comment: I tried with a space it didn't worked

Comment: Please update your question with modified code and the new error message.